# How to maintain php error log or any server log while using horizontal autoscaling aws?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, autoscaling

We are having a social network project which is having progressive traffic and to maintain this traffic we are using aws horizontal autoscaling in which servers are created dynamically and reduced dynamically So its difficult sometimes to track failures of server which were reduced. So please let me know if we can use any third party tool or something to maintain system log in autoscaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [centralized logging solution](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/logging/centralized-logging/), like for example the [ELK Stack](https://www.elastic.co/de/elk-stack).

The idea here is to (almost) immediately ship the logs to a centralized entity and hence to not have to worry about what happens with your autoscaled instances afterwards.